# Custom ChildAuthorizeAttribute to block content rather than redirect or Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Im trying to implement an AuthorizeAttribute so i can apply it to certain child actions the intention is to for example show the menus when the person is authorised and has access and otherwise to return without errors or redirections to login pages. Ive tried a few different return options but without success. Example below

```
//SideMenu.cshtml
    @{Html.RenderAction("AdminMenu", "Menu", "Menu");}

    @{Html.RenderAction("CommitteeMenu", "Menu", "Menu");}

    @{Html.RenderAction("MemberMenu", "Menu", "Menu");}

    @{Html.RenderAction("PublicMenu", "Menu", "Menu");}

//MenuController
         [BlockChildContentAuthorize(Roles = " Committee, Admin, Full_rights")]
         [ChildActionOnly]
         public virtual ActionResult CommitteeMenu()
         {
                 ....
         }

//Authorize.cs     
    public class BlockChildContentAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
        {    

            protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
            {
                if (filterContext.IsChildAction)
                {
                    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        filterContext.Result = new System.Web.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);

                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: What you want to do exactly if user is not authorized?

Comment: @ssilas777 Have updated to better illustrate intention. One example is a sidemenu which should only show the options which I have permission to, so someone who doesnt have the above roles shouldnt see the committee views content. i.e not render the views i dont have access to

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly manipulate view from custom attribute, Try something like this create a view bag if user is not authenticated and check it in the view.

```
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
         filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.IsAuthenticated = true;             
         if (filterContext.IsChildAction)
                {
                  if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
                  {
                  //User is not authenticated, Redirect to login page                                              
                  filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.IsAuthenticated = false;
                    }
                 //else user is authenticated, do nothing Action result will be executed.
                }else
               {
                 // not child action, perform operation.
               }         
        }
```

View - SideMenu.cshtml - Unauthenticated user can't see Committee Menu link (eg)

```
    @{Html.RenderAction("AdminMenu", "Menu", "Menu");}
     @if(ViewBag.IsAuthenticated)
     {
     Html.RenderAction("CommitteeMenu", "Menu", "Menu");
     }
     @{Html.RenderAction("MemberMenu", "Menu", "Menu");}
     @{Html.RenderAction("PublicMenu", "Menu", "Menu");}
```

Or else, you can directly check the user authentication in the view, so you can avoid a custom attribute.

```
    //SideMenu.cshtml
    @{Html.RenderAction("AdminMenu", "Menu", "Menu");}
    @if(HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
      Html.RenderAction("CommitteeMenu", "Menu", "Menu");
    }
    @{Html.RenderAction("MemberMenu", "Menu", "Menu");}
    @{Html.RenderAction("PublicMenu", "Menu", "Menu");}
```

Comment: thanks for the example but a redirect is the opposite of what i am asking for. I have code for 4 side menus' if a user doesnt have permission to 2 of the sidemenus then it should show the other 2, not redirect to the login page, just not render the 2 views which it doesnt have access to.

Comment: thanks but again this doesn't accomplish all the goals. It was checking that the user was authorised and authenticated against the roles listed, If not it should just return nothing no errors. I could wrap each call up in the razor but this is more verbose than i had intended.

Comment: What made you think it is returning errors, if user is not authenticated. It is just assigning value to view bag if user is not authenticated.As mentioned you can't do more in an authorization request.

Comment: i.e. no 403's. I have managed to get it to return the results of a blank view if the user was either not authenticated or unauthorised for the roles in question using a blank view as per filterContext.Result = new PartialViewResult(){ViewName = "..\\Shared\\Blank"};